# Delete order info section from email template in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to delete the **Order Information**  section on a Completed Order and Customer Invoice emails.

[image]

Can't find how to delete this in the:

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-completed-order.php
```

---

```php
<?php
/**
 * Subscription information template
 *
 * @author  Brent Shepherd / Chuck Mac
 * @package WooCommerce_Subscriptions/Templates/Emails
 * @version 1.5
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
?>
<?php if ( ! empty( $subscriptions ) ) : ?>
<h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Order Information:', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ) ?></h2>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #eee;" border="1" bordercolor="#eee">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Order', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Start Date', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php esc_html_e( 'End Date', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ( $subscriptions as $subscription ) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td scope="row" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( ( $is_admin_email ) ? wcs_get_edit_post_link( $subscription->id ) : $subscription->get_view_order_url() ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $subscription->get_order_number() ); ?></a></td>
            <td scope="row" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo esc_html( date_i18n( wc_date_format(), $subscription->get_time( 'start', 'site' ) ) ); ?></td>
            <td scope="row" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo esc_html( ( 0 < $subscription->get_time( 'end' ) ) ? date_i18n( wc_date_format(), $subscription->get_time( 'end', 'site' ) ) : __( 'When Cancelled', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ) ); ?></td>
            <td scope="row" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $subscription->get_formatted_order_total() ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to remove the entire action hook. This could effect other plugins that rely on it's presence. (Not to mention the order details are on the `woocommerce_email_order_details` details hook and not the `woocommerce_email_order_meta` hook anyway).

The proper way to remove the order details from all emails is to remove their callback function which is [`WC_Emails::order_details()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/3f4ffe8a494f672797cace9ad36098ea9b65222a/includes/class-wc-emails.php#L264-L270) which is added to the [`woocommerce_email_order_details` hook here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/3f4ffe8a494f672797cace9ad36098ea9b65222a/includes/class-wc-emails.php#L111)

You cannot call `remove_action()` directly and so must call it from inside an `add_action()` callback... after it has been added to it's hook, but before it has been run. In this case we're just going to sneak onto the same hook, but with an earlier priority. Also note, that `remove_action()` must have the same priority as the `add_action()` that you are trying to remove.

```
function so_39251827_remove_order_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    $mailer = WC()->mailer(); // get the instance of the WC_Emails class
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', array( $mailer, 'order_details' ), 10, 4 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'so_39251827_remove_order_details', 5, 4 );
```

**EDIT: Instructions for use**

1. Stop overriding the `emails/customer-completed-order.php` template and remove it from your theme. You do not need to edit it directly to solve this question.
2. Add the above code block to your theme's `functions.php` or preferably a custom-snippets plugin, such as [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/).

**EDIT #2: Remove Subscriptions Info Only**

Replace the above code with the following:

```
function so_39251827_remove_subscription_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', array( 'WC_Subscriptions_Order', 'add_sub_info_email' ), 15, 3 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'so_39251827_remove_subscription_details', 5, 4 );
```

Comment: HI,

I deleted 

`do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );`


The order information table was deleted, however also the order table was deleted as well.

I want to keep the order table - how can I retain this and delete just the order information table?

Please advise.

Comment: Do not delete the entire hook. As I explained, that will delete *all* actions attached to the hook. Please use the code I have provided.

Comment: Hi - sorry I misunderstood - I've inserted the code what I have on file and updated the original question.

Could you explain which parts I need to delete or add/replace - I don't have much skill in programming - thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Delete the entire `emails/customer-completed-order.php` from your theme. You do *not* need to override this template. You only need the code I have provided. See my edit for hopefully clearer instructions for use.

Comment: Hi,
The `emails/customer-completed-order.php` doesn't exist in my theme folder, I only have it here:
`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-completed-order.php`

I downloaded the code snippet plugin and have added your code into it - it deleted both order tables. 

Please advise - many thanks for your assistance here.

Comment: Did you delete the `do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );` line in `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-com‌​pleted-order.php`? If so, please revert this file to it's original state. It is always a bad idea to directly edit plugins.

Comment: Hi - no I didn't delete this line.
What I had done was added your code into the code snippet plugin and activated it - this resulted in removal of the order table details and the order information details - just like if I was to delete that line of code - the same thing will happen - both order table and order information would get deleted.
Please advise, thank you.

Comment: The order information table is *not* order information, it is subscription information. I didn't notice that at first, because the default template usually says "Subscription Information" and your template has been modified. See my edit to only remove the subscriptions information. Your theme is probably modifying the `emails/subscription-info.php` template, but assuming it hasn't changed the hook, this should work.

Comment: Hi - yes you're correct - I thought it was the other file as I could edit the subtitle on the email.

Going into the `emails/subscription-info.php` - I can see the details - I've added this onto the original question.

Comment: Fixed!
I deleted `<h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Order Information:', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ) ?></h2>`

Comment: AND:
`<tr>
   <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Order', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></th>
   <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Start Date', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></th>
   <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php esc_html_e( 'End Date', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></th>
   <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></th>
  </tr>`

Comment: AND: 
`<td scope="row" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( ( $is_admin_email ) ? wcs_get_edit_post_link( $subscription->id ) : $subscription->get_view_order_url() ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $subscription->get_order_number() ); ?></a></td>
   <td scope="row" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo esc_html( date_i18n( wc_date_format(), $subscription->get_time( 'start', 'site' ) ) ); ?></td>
   <td scope="row" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php ... </td>` (could fit it all)

Comment: Thank for your help! :)

Comment: If you use the code in my second edit, you don't need to modify the subscriptions template. In any case, remember not to modify it in the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin or your changes will be overridden when you update the plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Removing this part should fix the job
 `do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text );`

Comment: Hi,
The full line is:

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

Shall I delete this?

Answer (score -1):

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text );

try to remove this hook.

Comment: Hi,
The full line is:

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

Shall I delete this?

Comment: The order details are not on this hook. And it is a bad idea to remove the entire hook when you only need to remove the action that is added to the hook.