# Removing customer details and addresses from email notification templates

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, hook-woocommerce

I am working on a theme created for woocommerce, built by some other German developer. I have created my child theme and using child theme's functions.php to make changes to functionality of the website.

When a customer orders a product, he receives an email with order table, customer information and  billing address and customer shipping. 
I want to remove everything below the table and add my own text (customer info + billing, shipping and pick up address as well).

I have added my own text right below the order table in email that goes to customer, however I am unable to delete the information that shows by default below my custom added text. I found the hook responsible for fetching and showing that data is `woocommerce_email_order_meta`, but I don't know how to remove it or prevent it from executing. I don't want to make changes in the template files, I want to do it all by hooks.

So far I have tried doing it like this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

I followed the link: [Delete order info section from email template in woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251827/delete-order-info-section-from-email-template-in-woocommerce) and tried the following code as well, **but didn't work**.

```
function so_39251827_remove_order_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    $mailer = WC()->mailer(); // get the instance of the WC_Emails class
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', array( $mailer, 'order_details' ), 10, 4 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'so_39251827_remove_order_details', 5, 4 );
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Explanations** - In all email notification templates you have this:

```
/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

After some research in WooCommerce core files and some test, I have removed successfully the customer details, the billing and shipping address from notification emails as you wished.

**Here is the code:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'removing_customer_details_in_emails', 5, 4 );
function removing_customer_details_in_emails( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    $mailer = WC()->mailer();
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', array( $mailer, 'customer_details' ), 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', array( $mailer, 'email_addresses' ), 20 );
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and fully functional.

---

References :

- [Class WC_Emails customer_details() method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Emails.html#_customer_details)
- [Class WC_Emails email_addresses() method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Emails.html#_email_addresses)

Comment: Wow!! It's working! Thank you very much! May God bless you!

Comment: LoicTheAztec Thanks again for help, I could successfully finish the project. But now I want to learn, how did you reach this far? How exactly did you do your research? How did you come to know that it was `woocommerce_email_customer_details` hook and not `woocommerce_email_order_meta`? and then how did you find `array($mailer, 'customer_details')` arguments? and how did you find what `WC()->mailer()` does?
Please suggest, where can I learn all these in layman terms, I am very new in woocommerce. Thanks!!