# Custom formatted adresses section in WooCommerce email notifications sent to admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

i've been searching around for a long time now and for some reason i cant get it to work.

i need to hide from admin email only, but for some reason it also apply to customer email. i want to hide, shipping from the other, and in client details, phone and email adress.

```
  <?php  
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'custom_woocommerce_get_order_item_totals' );

 function custom_woocommerce_get_order_item_totals( $totals ) {
  unset( $totals['shipping'] );
      return $totals;
  }
  ///// so far is what i got to hide everything and not just the specific fields i wanted
  function removing_customer_details_in_emails( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
$wmail = WC()->mailer();
if($sent_to_admin)
remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', array( $wmail, 'email_addresses' ), 20, 3 );
 }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'removing_customer_details_in_emails', 5, 4 );
```

as mentioned above it hides the fields from the customer email as well and i need just for the admin email, and for some reason all i found did not work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide billing phone, billing email and shipping address on email notifications sent to the admin, use the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'sent_to_admin_custom_email_addresses', 5, 4 );
function sent_to_admin_custom_email_addresses( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    if( in_array( $email->id, array( 'new_order', 'cancelled_order', 'failed_order' ) ) ) {
        $mailer = WC()->mailer();
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', array( $mailer, 'email_addresses' ), 20 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'custom_email_addresses', 20, 1 );
    }
}

function custom_email_addresses( $order ) {
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) :

    $text_align = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';
    $address    = $order->get_formatted_billing_address();

    ?><table id="addresses" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: top; margin-bottom: 40px; padding:0;" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border:0; padding:0;" valign="top" width="50%">
                <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
                <address class="address">
                    <?php echo wp_kses_post( $address ? $address : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?>
                </address>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Related: [Removing customer details and addresses from email notification templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743156/removing-customer-details-and-addresses-from-email-notification-templates/39745500#39745500)

Comment: i copy and pasted the code and does hide billing phone and adress as i wanted but it keeps doing it on client email as well, i don't know what is causing it, i use this ........... if(!$sent_to_admin) indeed only admin see the addresses and not the client, but some reason it cant be the other way

Comment: still applying to both emails , the rest is perfect

Comment: @tyresehumphreys Just tested my code now on last WooCommerce version (last WP) using storefront theme and **it works** just fine and changes are only applied to admin emails.. So there is something else that is making trouble in your case… It can be some other code customizations that you have done, a plugin or your theme.

Comment: im using oceanwp theme, will try deactivating all plugins and see, thanks for ur help

Comment: @tyresehumphreys Check that your email templates are not overridden by the theme and /or up to date

Comment: im using a multi site with subdirectories, i can't tell if that is the issue, but after removing all plugins except woo and changed the theme to store front and nothing i decided to go with css and i got it working with and if , elseif .................. if ( $email->id == 'new_order' ) {}
 elseif ( $email->id == 'customer_on_hold_order' ) {} this got it working on admin and customer, will try to adapat this to your code

Comment: @tyresehumphreys I tested that on another web site and it works too. My if statement check if the email notification is "New Order", "Cancelled Order" or "Failed Order" (notifications sent to the admin)… So this is the right working way.

Comment: @loicTheAstec, im completely sure is something on my end, thanks for ur asistance is till be using ur code